# Calculate percentage over time on very large data frames

Tags: r

I'm new to R and my problem is I know what I need to do, just not how to do it in R.  I have an very large data frame from a web services load test, ~20M observations. I has the following variables:

```
epochtime, uri, cache (hit or miss)
```

I'm thinking I need to do a coule of things. I need to subset my data frame for the top 50 distinct URIs then for each observation in each subset calculate the % cache hit at that point in time. The end goal is a plot of cache hit/miss % over time by URI

I have read, and am still reading various posts here on this topic but R is pretty new and I have a deadline. I'd appreciate any help I can get

EDIT:

I can't provide exact data but it looks like this, its at least 20M observations I'm retrieving from a Mongo database. Time is epoch and we're recording many thousands per second so time has a lot of dupes, thats expected. There could be more than 50 uri, I only care about the top 50. The end result would be a line plot over time of % TCP_HIT to the total occurrences by URI. Hope thats clearer

```
time                uri                 action
1355683900          /some/uri           TCP_HIT
1355683900          /some/other/uri     TCP_HIT 
1355683905          /some/other/uri     TCP_MISS
1355683906          /some/uri           TCP_MISS
```

Comment: Please supply a representative example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you provide a reproducible example of your data, and are specific about your problem (providing your desired output) it would be a lot easier to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `aggregate` function.

Call your data frame u:

```
> u
        time             uri   action
1 1355683900       /some/uri  TCP_HIT
2 1355683900 /some/other/uri  TCP_HIT
3 1355683905 /some/other/uri TCP_MISS
4 1355683906       /some/uri TCP_MISS
```

Here is the ratio of hits for a subset (using the order of factor levels, TCP_HIT=1, TCP_MISS=2 as alphabetical order is used by default), with ten-second intervals:

```
ratio <- function(u) aggregate(u$action ~ u$time %/% 10,
         FUN=function(x) sum((2-as.numeric(x))/length(x)))
```

Now use lapply to get the final result:

```
lapply(seq_along(levels(u$uri)),
    function(l) list(uri=levels(u$uri)[l],
     hits=ratio(u[as.numeric(u$uri) == l,])))


[[1]]
[[1]]$uri
[1] "/some/other/uri"

[[1]]$hits
  u$time%/%10 u$action
1   135568390      0.5


[[2]]
[[2]]$uri
[1] "/some/uri"

[[2]]$hits
  u$time%/%10 u$action
1   135568390      0.5
```

Or otherwise filter the data frame by URI before computing the ratio.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'll go try to figure out exactly what you did and how to plot it. :) I do see that I have a list to work with now though

Comment: I'm not sure this is working. I ran this against a 12M obs. dataseet and instead of a % like you show above I get:
`[[925]]
[[925]]$uri
[1] "env/service/2/method/blah"

[[925]]$hits
  u$time%/%10 u$action
1   135561363       -3
2   135561382       -3
3   135561386       -3
4   135561473       -3
5   135561507       -7`

Comment: Nevermind, ran this on another dataset and I'm getting numbers that look correct. I'm stuck on plotting this though. R list seem to behave differently that in any other language. What I want to do is for every  item in the list, plot the nested list.
`> h[1]
[[1]]
[[1]]$uri
[1] "/service/0/method"

[[1]]$hits
  u$time%/%10 u$action
1   135561701        0
2   135561707        0
3   135561710        0
4   135561713        0`

any suggestions would be appreciated,

Answer (score 2):

@MatthewLundberg's code is the right idea.  Specifically, you want something that utilizes the split-apply-combine strategy.

Given the size of your data, though, I'd take a look at the `data.table` package.

You can see why visually [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11562850/636656)--data.table is just faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thought it would be useful to share my solution to the plotting part of them problem.

My R "noobness" my shine here but this is what I came up with. It makes a basic line plot. Its plotting the actual value, I haven't done any conversions.

```
for ( i in 1:length(h)) {
  name <- unlist(h[[i]][1])  
  dftemp <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,h[[i]][2]))
  names(dftemp) <-  c("time", "cache")
  plot(dftemp$time,dftemp$cache, type="o")
  title(main=name)
}
```